# Android Chat Push Notifications Socket.Io NodeJS Server

Tags: android, node.js, android-activity, socket.io

I built a nodejs based chat server with socket.io as underlying library. The chat client is in an Android app and it uses https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java

Currently, push notifications are determined based on number of sockets connected. (1:1 chat, ideally, if there are 2 , implies both are available)

I subscribe whenever I open Chat Window or comes into focus after going out, disconnect whenever I move out of Chat window or window goes out of focus.

Cases to handle are:
1. App is closed
2. App open but user on some other app
3. User on the app but elsewhere not on chat windows
4. User on chat summary window
5. User on 1:1 chat with someone - notifs shouldn't come from chats on this window
6. User on 1:1 with someone - we should get push notifs for chats by someone else

1 Case pending which is main bug - If user is on App and on Chat window, closes the app, the socket connection is still alive as activity is not cleaning up entirely. This causes all subsequent runs to break the push notifs.

What is best way to resolve this ? Any other solutions ?

Comment: You have to revise your cases again it is a little bit complex. To make it a little bit simple,Whenever socket.io connection does not exist, send a push notification that a broadcast receiver can handle it. Otherwise you have to keep socket.io session open.